# Numerical range of a product of a matrix with diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix $A$ with numerical radius $r(A)$ which is irreducible. If I multiply the matrix $A$ by diagonal matrix $D$ such that $0<d_{ii}\leq 1$ with $\prod_i d_{ii}<1$. We have a property that numerical range $\mathcal N (DA)\subseteq \mathcal N(D)\mathcal N(A)\subseteq \mathcal N(A)$. I believe the numerical radius of $r(DA)<r(A)$.